# Difference between StockStateInterface and StockRegistryInterface

Tags: magento2.2, api

I was using StockStateInterface to get stock qty, it was working fine in development and staging server but was not working in production server.

Then I used StockRegistryInterface to get the result and it worked on the production server.

Why it happened so?

I used this:

```
\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockState, 
\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
```